# Xcode build - Process product packaging error

Tags: xcode

Suddenly Xcode 8 has started giving me this error while building on device.

Process product packaging

"error: class '(null)' of input object does not respond to either selector writeToFile:options:error: or writeToFile:atomically"

Does anyone know how to get rid of this. And no, clean or restart does not work.